# A metric space is Lindelöf iff it has a countable cover by $\epsilon$-balls for every $\epsilon$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A space is Lindelöf if every cover has a countable subcover.

Show that a metric space $(X, d)$ is Lindelöf if and only if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a countable cover by $\epsilon$-balls.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: One direction is immediate. For the other direction, suppose that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable cover of $X$ by open $\epsilon$-balls. By taking $\epsilon=\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, show that $X$ is separable. Then show that a separable metric space is second countable and therefore Lindelöf.

Note, though, that your definition of *Lindelöf* isn’t quite right: $X$ is Lindelöf if every *open* cover of $X$ has a countable subcover.

Comment: Once you have a countable cover of $X$ by open $\frac1n$-balls for each $n\in\mathbb N$, you could just show that the union of those covers is a countable base, instead of taking a detour through separability.

Comment: @bof: Good point. I was thinking that that the results in the last sentence of the first paragraph might already be known to the OP, but if they’re not, your shortcut is certainly the way to go.